# Specifying multiple ordering rules

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2 and I have a complex ordering question or problem, for which I cannot find a solution.

To better explain, I've posted a sample resultant query below. In this, we're trying to display a hierarchy of locations, but while the parent/child relationships are ordered correctly, they are not alphabetical within their relationships. As you can see, both "East Coast" and "West Coast" are the top-level locations as their parent location (f_locationparent) equals (0). However, I'd like "East Coast" to display before "West Coast". Obviously, I cannot simply order by `f_locationname`, then by `f_lineage`, because the relationships would then not be displayed in the proper order. Important note: top-level locations will always have a parent location of (0), as they have no parents.

```
f_locationid    f_locationparent    f_locationname  f_level f_lineage
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
4               0                   West Coast      0       0_4
5               4                   Los Angeles     1       0_4_5
6               5                   Del Rey         2       0_4_5_6
7               5                   Reseda          2       0_4_5_7
8               5                   Crenshaw        2       0_4_5_8
9               0                   East Coast      0       0_9
10              9                   New York City   1       0_9_10
1               10                  Queens          2       0_9_10_1
2               10                  Bronx           2       0_9_10_2
3               10                  Manhattan       2       0_9_10_3
```

Below is the current query:

```
;WITH   cte_locationlineage AS 
 (
 SELECT  a.f_locationid, a.f_locationparent, a.f_locationname, 0 AS f_level,
   CONVERT(varchar(30), '0_' + convert(varchar(10), f_locationid)) f_lineage
 FROM    tb__templocations a 
 WHERE   f_locationparent = '0' 
 UNION ALL
    SELECT  a.f_locationid,
           a.f_locationparent,
           a.f_locationname,
           c.f_level + 1,
           CONVERT(varchar(30), f_lineage + '_' 
                   + convert(varchar(10), a.f_locationid))
   FROM    cte_locationlineage c
   JOIN    tb__templocations a
       ON a.f_locationparent = c.f_locationID
 )
 SELECT *
 FROM   cte_locationlineage c
 ORDER BY f_lineage
```

As you can see, it is ordered based on lineage, which is combination of the location IDs (f_locationID). Unfortunately, as you can see, location IDs don't always line up alphabetically.

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b09af) is a SQL Fiddle, so you can see how it works.

In the end, using the same data, this is the resultant query that I'd like to see, where within the relationships under the parent, items are ordered alphabetically. So for the "East Coast" grandparent and "New York City" parent, the children listed under that are alphabetical.

```
f_locationid    f_locationparent    f_locationname  f_level f_lineage
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
9               0                   East Coast      0       0_9
10              9                   New York City   1       0_9_10
2               10                  Bronx           2       0_9_10_2
3               10                  Manhattan       2       0_9_10_3    
1               10                  Queens          2       0_9_10_1
4               0                   West Coast      0       0_4
5               4                   Los Angeles     1       0_4_5
8               5                   Crenshaw        2       0_4_5_8  
6               5                   Del Rey         2       0_4_5_6 
7               5                   Reseda          2       0_4_5_7
```

Comment: If you order the items by their full path, you can get the desired ordering easily. Please check my second answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()` to help:

```
;WITH   cte_locationlineage AS 
 (
 SELECT  a.f_locationid, a.f_locationparent, a.f_locationname, 0 AS f_level,
       CONVERT(varchar(30), '0_' + convert(varchar(10), f_locationid)) f_lineage,
       CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY f_locationname) as decimal(8,4)) as ordering
 FROM    tb__templocations a 
 WHERE   f_locationparent = '0' 
 UNION ALL
    SELECT  a.f_locationid,
         a.f_locationparent,
         a.f_locationname,
         c.f_level + 1,
         CONVERT(varchar(30), f_lineage + '_' + convert(varchar(10), a.f_locationid)),
         cast(c.ordering + (CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY a.f_locationname) 
           as decimal(8,4))/POWER(10,c.f_level + 1)) as decimal(8,4))
   FROM    cte_locationlineage c
   JOIN    tb__templocations a
       ON a.f_locationparent = c.f_locationID
 )
 SELECT *
 FROM   cte_locationlineage c
 ORDER BY c.ordering
```

This way, you are doing a combination of your level and your location name to order things in the list.

It's worth noting, though, that if your table is very large, this may not be practical. `ROW_NUMBER()` can get fairly slow as you run into larger and larger datasets.

**EDIT:** One thing that becomes an issue is if you have more than nine rows in a level, with the above example. You have to increase the magnitude to reflect enough "spaces" to hold the information. For instance, this works for up to 99 rows per level:

```
;WITH   cte_locationlineage AS 
 (
 SELECT  a.f_locationid, a.f_locationparent, a.f_locationname, 0 AS f_level,
         CONVERT(varchar(30), '0_' + convert(varchar(10), f_locationid)) f_lineage,
         CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY f_locationname) as decimal(12,8)) as ordering
 FROM    tb__templocations a 
 WHERE   f_locationparent = '0' 
 UNION ALL
    SELECT  a.f_locationid,
           a.f_locationparent,
           a.f_locationname,
           c.f_level + 1,
           CONVERT(varchar(30), f_lineage + '_' + convert(varchar(10), a.f_locationid)),
           cast(c.ordering + (CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY a.f_locationname) as decimal(12,8))
                    /POWER(10,(c.f_level + 1)*2)) as decimal(12,8))
   FROM    cte_locationlineage c
   JOIN    tb__templocations a
       ON a.f_locationparent = c.f_locationID
 )
 SELECT *
 FROM   cte_locationlineage c
 ORDER BY c.ordering
```

Obviously, this will get cumbersome if you go much higher than 999 rows per level, but I suspect that shouldn't be an issue given your comments.

I'm curious if someone has a more clever way to accomplish the same thing using binary; I'm going to see if I can work out the math later tonight.

Comment: Yes, this is simple, elegant, and [works great - even with Miami thrown in](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/53bc57/2). (And, if the table is very large, the recursive CTE approach already limits practicality.)

Comment: This is exquisite, thank you. I never imagined the solution would fit within the query that was already used. I thought for sure the answer involved wiping out what I had and starting over, so thank you, sincerely. At most, I may have 1000 rows in the table. I'm currently at about 600 rows, and this runs instantaneously (so low, in fact, it runs in 0.0002 seconds (200 microseconds).

Comment: I found a problem. Where it seems that if we reach a parent who has 10 or more children that we end up with an order of 5.8, 5.9, 6.0... | Then, when we reach 6.0, we can have multiple items where the order is 6.0, throwing the order out of balance.

Comment: @Beems Yes, you have to increase the order of magnitude...so change decimal(8,4) to decimal (12,8) and multiply your POWER exponent by 2. So you have to keep what your possible combinations are in mind. If you think you'll have over 99 rows per level, then you'd have to level by 3, etc. I can update the answer if you'd like, with a working example.

Comment: @Beems There's probably a more clever way to do this using binary that's beyond my ability short of sitting down and working through the math. :)

Comment: Please do update the answer so that future searchers ending up on this topic have the same answer. I greatly appreciate your help, sincerely.

Comment: Nice. A variation that does not use powers, only strings. Works with up to 33 levels and up to 99 items with same parent: **[sql-fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b09af/29)**. Can be easily extended by changing (for example) the `'0'` to `'000'`, the `varchar(2)` `to varchar(4)` in order to have up to 9999 items per parent. The `varchar(99)` would have to become `varchar((4+1)*X)` where X is the max level of the hierarchy.

Answer (score 2):

You can just order the rows by full path name, using a non-used character for concatenating names.

```
WITH   cte_locationlineage AS (
    SELECT  a.F_LocationId, a.f_locationparent, a.f_locationname, 
            0 AS f_level,
            CONVERT(varchar(30), '0_' + convert(varchar(10), F_LocationId)) as f_lineage,
            CONVERT(varchar(max), a.f_locationname) as Fullname -- Add this line
    FROM    tb__templocations a 
    WHERE   f_locationparent = '0' 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  a.F_LocationId,
            a.f_locationparent,
            a.f_locationname,
            c.f_level + 1,
            CONVERT(varchar(30), f_lineage + '_' 
                   + convert(varchar(10), a.F_LocationId)),
            CONVERT(varchar(max), c.fullname + '_' + a.f_locationname) -- Add this line
   FROM     cte_locationlineage c
   JOIN     tb__templocations a ON a.f_locationparent = c.F_LocationId)

SELECT *
FROM   cte_locationlineage c
ORDER BY fullname -- Change this line
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b09af/31)

Comment: This is an interesting solution. Using the concatenated "fullname" field, you could actually break it back apart in codebehind and use it to display "breadcrumb" navigation back up the hierarchy.

Answer (score -7):

Order by first the top parent name and then the lineage

```
ORDER BY (select f_locationname from cte_locationlineage d 
  where d.F_Lineage = substring(c.F_lineage,1,3)), f_lineage
```

**UPDATE**

To handle multi-digit id's:

```
ORDER BY (select f_locationname from cte_locationlineage d 
  where d.f_level = 0 and c.F_LiNEAGE + '_' like d.f_lineage + '[_]%'), f_lineage
```

Comment: No, this won't work, for starters it assumes that all location_id values will be single-digit (you can't hardcode the substring like that), and [it demonstrably doesn't return the right results anyway](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/53bc57/3). Never mind additional performance implications from sorting based on a correlated subquery...

Comment: Oh, so many dislikes !! :) Well, that was just a quick proposition, you get the idea. the comparison can be tweaked a little to handle multi-digit id's also.

Comment: It's not about liking or disliking. Your updated solution [doesn't work either](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/53bc57/6) - did you try either of these queries? You're still ordering by `lineage` - the OP wants to order all elements at the same level *alphabetically* by name, not by lineage.

Comment: Yes, of course I tried them. It's just that I thought the alphabetical ordering was intended for the top level items only. Missed the part that the subnodes in the same level would be sorted too.